# Measuring accuracy of multiple binary output Neural net in R

Tags: r, neural-network

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899823/r-subscript-of-dataframe-with-condition-values-by-a-vector) SO question, I have a data.frame of floats which I would like to convert to a set of Boolean values.

Specifically, I would like to go through a matrix (data.frame) where each cell is replaced with "if this cell is the maximum of all cells in this row"

For example, given the following data.frame,

```
row.names   net.result.1  net.result.2  net.result.3 net.result.4
1            0.000013,     0.0156616,    0.000005,    0.999959
2            0.000046,     0.0145417,    0.000005,    0.999945
3            0.938103,     0.0043157,    0.000007,    0.002126
4            0.000000,     0.0000000,    0.999811,    0.000000
```

Produce the following binary values:

```
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE
TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
dat == apply(dat, 1, max) 
        V1    V2    V3    V4
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: This seems to return a vector of only the max values. The 'max' operator seems to be returning the max value of each row.

Comment: I've updated the question with a more detailed representation of my data

Comment: @Peaches491 Sorry I don't get your point. `apply(dat, 1, max)` returns the max of each row, that I compare to your matrixx...

Comment: OHHH. I missed the '==', and was only using a single equals sign. Works perfectly now! Thank you